# XML XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am new to XML, XSLT. I have a input xml file, and the target xml file. I need to write the xslt code that generates the target xml. Can anyone please help me understand this. The root Element bill is mapped with Document, and
the remaining child and sub-child  elements are mapped with para. I am struggling wo write the transformation code. The first is input and the second is the target xml code: Can anyone please help me with the transformation.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformation.xsl"?>
   <bill bill-stage="Enrolled" bill-type="abc" dms- 
    id="1234" key="1" public- 
     private="public" stage-count="1">
  <main>
  <longTitle>
  <docTitle style="-uslm-lc:I123" class="centered 
   fontsize18">Hello</docTitle>
   <officialTitle style="-uslm-lc:I1234" class="centered fontsize8">To 
    name the Department of Electrical Engineering.<br 
    verticalSpace="08pt"/></officialTitle>
   </longTitle>
   <enactingFormula style="-uslm-lc:I2334">  This related to Student 
      Homework Submission on time</enactingFormula>
   <section style="-uslm-lc:I235"><num value="1">SECTION 1. </num> 
  <heading>Report Submission</heading>
  <content style="-uslm-lc:I1236">  The Department of Electrical 
  Engineering has come to a conclusion that students who do not submit 
  assignement on time will not be considered to sit in the finals
  </content>
  </section>
 </main>
  <signatures>
   <signature><role style="-uslm-lc:I114">Associate Department 
     Advisor</role></signature>
   <signature><role style="-uslm-lc:I114">Electrical Engineering Dept. 
    </role></signature>
  </signatures>
 </bill>
```

target XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
      <para format="6655" loc="05">Hello</para>
        <para format="66554" loc="11">To name the Department  of 
           Electrical Engineering. </para>
         <para format="6501" loc="20">This related to Student Homework 
           Submission on time</para>
           <para format="6501" loc="46"><?xpp fv;1?>SECTION 1. <?xpp 
               fv;4?>Report Submission <?xpp rs-font?>The Department of 
                 Electrical Engineering has come to a conclusion that 
                     students who do not submit assignement on time will 
                       not be considered to sit in the finals</para>
            <para format="6501" loc="14">Associate Department 
             Advisor</para>
            <para format="6501" loc="14">Electrical Engineering Dept. 
         </para>
      </document>
```

I have tried writing the following code:

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes">
    <xsl:template  match="/">
        <xsl:element name ="document">
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="bill"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:element name = "bill">
            <!--</xsl:copy-of select "*"/>-->
            <xsl:for-each select="bill/main/longTitle">
                <xsl:apply-template select="para">
                    <xsl:value-of select="docTitle"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="officialTitle"/>
                </xsl:element>   
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="bill/main/">
                <xsl:value-of select="enactingFormula"/>

            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:for-each select="bill/main/section">
                <xsl:value-of select="num">
                <xsl:value-of select="heading">
                <xsl:value-of select="content">

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:output>
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Is your code giving you a specific error message? Are you unsure of the correct syntax for one of the elements? Is the code doing something other than what you expected it to do?

Comment: I need help with the mapping. the root element "bill" is mapped with "document" and the remaining all the child element is mapped to "para". How to address this in XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bill"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//docTitle">
    <para format="6655" loc="05">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//officialTitle">
  <para format="66554" loc="11">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//enactingFormula">
  <para format="6501" loc="20">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//section">
  <para format="6501" loc="46">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </para>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="num[parent::section]">
    <xsl:text>&lt;?xpp fv;1?&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="heading[parent::section]">
    <xsl:text>&lt;?xpp fv;4?&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="content[parent::section]">
    <xsl:text> &lt;?xpp rs-font?&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="signatures">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="signature">
    <para format="6501" loc="14">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>**
```

Comment: I wrote the above XSLT code which matched the target xml.